# N-dependent (even) function integral

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, even-and-odd-functions

We want to compute, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the following integral:  $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[n]{1+x}+\sqrt[n]{1-x}}dx$$

My attempt: 
if $n$ is odd, the integral is trivially equal to $0$ since $x^n/(\sqrt[n]{1+x}+\sqrt[n]{1-x})$ is itself an odd function. If $n$ is even, so does $x^n/(\sqrt[n]{1+x}+\sqrt[n]{1-x})$ and therefore $$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[n]{1+x}+\sqrt[n]{1-x}}dx=2\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\sqrt[n]{1+x}+\sqrt[n]{1-x}}dx$$ but this is not really helping. Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Is there any particular reason you expect the integral to have a closed form?

Comment: For shortness, $\sqrt[n]{1+x}=a$, $\sqrt[n]{1-x}=b$. Multiply above and below by  $a^{n-1}b^0-a^{n-2}b^1+\cdots+a^0 b^{n-1}$ so you no longer have a fraction but a sum. However, it may not help much, you still have to integrate integrals of the form $\int x^n \sqrt[n]{(1-x)^k (1+x)^{n-1-k}}dx$.

Comment: Just by checking Mathematica output, it doesn't look like there's a nice closed form solution in general.